# db query optimisation with alternate ways to handle expandable_fields

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I am using `ExpanderSerializerMixin` as follows:

```
class StateSerializer(ExpanderSerializerMixin):
    class Meta:
        model = State
        fields = ['name', 'population']


class CountrySerializer(ExpanderSerializerMixin):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ('name', 'population')

        expandable_fields = {
            'states': StateSerializer,
        }

class PersonSerializer(FlexFieldsModelSerializer):
    country = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'country', 'occupation')

        expandable_fields = {
            'country': CountrySerializer,
        }
```

This created a performance overhead on the db. To enhance the performance of my serialiser, how can I override the expand or create my own mixin?

Comment: what do you mean by "**performance overhead on the db**"? too many queries or slow queries? or any other behavior?

Comment: Too many queries. If I have 100 states, there are 100 db queries.

Comment: in your views, you can override `get_queryset()` and add `select_related` to the queryset.

Comment: @NalinDobhal That helped reduce the number or queries. Thanks.

Comment: What I am looking for is implementing select_related in the serializer; something like  http://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/